# Visual Studio SDK - How to detect installed extensions programatically?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-sdk

How can I get a list of all installed Visual Studio extensions programatically? Also, is it possible to detect if a specific extension is already installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [IVsExtensionManager.GetInstalledExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.extensionmanager.ivsextensionmanager.getinstalledextensions.aspx). You can get an ExtensionManager instance with Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsExtensionManager)) as IVsExtensionManager.